# How convert const wchar_t* from C DLL to C# string automatically

Tags: c#, c++, dll, wchar-t, interopservices

It is just a curiosity. Perhaps there is a person in this world who did such things:

I have to export C function and load it from C# code via DllImport

```
const wchar_t * SysGetLibInfo() {
    return dllmanager.SysGetLibInfo();
}
```

The best things to do that, and it is recommended widely, is to declare IntPtr and then convert it to string using some function. In other words, something like this

```
[DllImport(dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr SysGetLibInfo(); 
// ...
Marshal.PtrToStringUni(SysGetLibInfo());
```

This approach works. But Is there a way to do that automatically? To make SysGetLibInfo to be returning a string? I found some suggestions like this:

```
[DllImport(dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
private static extern string SysGetLibInfo();
```

But it doesn't work, and, according to a variety of examples and scant reports it should not work.

Is there a way to write my own attribute like MarshalAs which will convert IntPtr to string? Something similar to this:

```
[DllImport(dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MyOwnMarshalPtrToStringUni]
private static extern string SysGetLibInfo();
```

Thanks in advance for any information or useful links, examples, books. Again, it is just a curiosity.

P.S. Suggestion to wrap SysGetLibInfo with a separate function which convert result to string using PtrToStringUni is not an option ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override MarshalAs but you can use custom marshalling instead

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w22x2hw6.aspx

```
  [DllImport(dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(MyMarshaller))]
  private static extern string SysGetLibInfo();
```

Comment: Thanks, it is an option. There is no way to do such a thing simpler than implementing ICustomMarshaler interface, is there?

Comment: Custom marshaller for standard string type? Smells like another wheel.

Comment: Hm. To allow this "[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(MyMarshaller))]" I need create class MyMarshaller which implements ICustomMarshaler interface, correct? In MyMarshaller#MarshalNativeToManaged I will use PtrToStringUni.... Or do you mean that there is a standard class which already does this?

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem is with the `LPWStr`:

> you cannot use the LPWStr value with an unmanaged string *unless the
>   string was created by using the unmanaged CoTaskMemAlloc function*

This works fine. Native code:

```
// header
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) wchar_t* SysGetLibInfo(void);

// implementation
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) wchar_t* SysGetLibInfo(void)
{
    return TEXT("Hello from unmanaged world!");
}
```

Managed code:

```
    [DllImport("NativeLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    static extern string SysGetLibInfo();
```

If you'll change native function this way:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) wchar_t* SysGetLibInfo(void)
{
    wchar_t* pStr = (wchar_t*)CoTaskMemAlloc(100);

    ZeroMemory(pStr, 100);

    wcscpy(pStr, TEXT("Hello from unmanaged world!"));

    return pStr;
}
```

then `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]` will work too.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I'd not like to do this way. Let's imagine that DLL is written already and it returns const wchar_t * :). Thank you very much!

Comment: Let's imagine that DLL is written already - so, use `LPTStr` when marshaling. This works in both cases (with `CoTaskMemAlloc` and without it). There's no need for custom marshaller here.

Comment: LPTStr doesn't work and sometimes summons System.AccessViolationException. And there is nothing extraordinary according to MS documentation